# how to group_by with tables' key name

Tags: json, jq, edit

My input json file:

```
{ "london": [ "x", 0 ] }
{ "london": [ "y", 97 ] }
{ "paris": [ "x", 15 ] }
{ "paris": [ "y", 8 ] }
```

I try to group by  key and make the output:

```
{ "london":  ["x", 0], ["y", 97] },
{ "paris":   ["x", 15], ["y", 8] }
```

or:

```
{ "london": [ {"x", 0}, {"y", 97} ] },
{ "paris":  [ {"x", 15}, {"y", 8} ] }
```

The following command give me an error message:

```
 jq -s 'group_by(keys_unsorted[0]) | map({(.[0]): map(.[1])})'
```

jq: error (at :4): Cannot index object with number

I try to change the numbers to strings, but, it does not help.
I guess that I missed something in the map *(?)*

EDIT:

Extantion regarding the answer from @pmf.
The Original source is:

```
 {
   "city": "london",
   "zoo": [
     { "room": { "name": "x" }, "gpu": { "id": "fish",  "sum": 0 } },
     { "room": { "name": "y" }, "gpu": { "id": "zebra", "sum": 97 } }
    ]
  }
  {
    "city": "paris",
    "zoo": [
       { "room": { "name": "x" }, "gpu": { "id": "fish",  "sum": 15 } },
       { "room": { "name": "y" }, "gpu": { "id": "zebra", "sum": 8 } }
    ]
  }
```

and I try to get the output as above. I started with following:

```
      jq -c '.city as $j | foreach .zoo[] as $i (.; .; {($j): [$i.room.name, $i.gpu.sum]})'
```

then i stuck and @pmf helped me. Can I do it else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected outputs aren't valid JSON (either they lack array brackets, or they have abundant commas). The first of the two even lists multiple values to a single object key, which is not possible (unless the value is enclosed within array brackets). Here's how to start collecting from a stream:

```bash
jq -n 'reduce (inputs | to_entries)[] as $e ({}; .[$e.key] += [$e.value])'
```

```json
{
  "london": [
    [
      "x",
      0
    ],
    [
      "y",
      97
    ]
  ],
  "paris": [
    [
      "x",
      15
    ],
    [
      "y",
      8
    ]
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/5IQ3gCmkHoT)

From here, decide what your (valid) target structure should look like, and, if needed, ask another question based on that.

---

Edit 1: Your approach using `group_by` relies on the premise that each input object consists of just one key. If you want to pursue that approach, create objects with each first of a group's first key:

```bash
jq -sc 'group_by(keys_unsorted[])[] | {(.[0] | keys_unsorted[]): [.[][]]}'
```

```json
{"london":[["x",0],["y",97]]}
{"paris":[["x",15],["y",8]]}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IRB_4sOstAw)

---

Edit 2: Your original filter can be simplified to `{(.city): (.zoo[] | [.room.name, .gpu.sum])}` ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/venGoYLt6km)), which then can be concatenated with this post's first approach by replacing `inputs` with the above ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7jNxKjW8tFc)), which in turn can be simplified (quite similarly to the previous simplification) by not generating objects to just destructure them again, but by directly operating on the original input data instead:

```bash
jq -c '{(.city): .zoo | map([.room.name, .gpu.sum])}'
```

```json
{"london":[["x",0],["y",97]]}
{"paris":[["x",15],["y",8]]}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Lcyp91h8vnn)

Comment: funny, but the  input file came as output from jq commnd.  so, i tried to
concatenate your answer to the jq's pipe and it doesnt work.  instead,
i piped the first jq  by bash's pip to the second jq command and then
it it works.  thanks pmf.

Comment: @Udi If you want your existing jq filter (which produces said input) to be combined with any follow-up filter from this page into one jq call (which is usually more efficient than calling jq multiple times in succession), you'd need to disclose that existing filter (at least for the parts producing the stream), so we can pinpoint what to connect and how.

Comment: I edited my question and now it contains the source of the input include the jq fileter.  Can you see a way to improve the filter?

Comment: @Udi "Edit 2" addresses the simplification and concatenation of both filters.

Comment: why did you put the .city into parentheses?

Comment: @Udi See the manual about [object construction](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#object-construction): "Key expressions other than constant literals, identifiers, or variable references, need to be parenthesized".